# jssor video images disappear after the first play

Tags: video, jssor

When the first "run" of the videos ends, the images from YouTube disappear (you see a black background instead).

Example here:
http://www.jssor.com/demos/video-gallery.html

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  I narrowed it down to the iframe parameter:

enablejsapi

Whenever that is set to 1 it removes the video image.  Not sure why but when it set to 0 or remove completely it solves the problem.

Comment: In addition, it allows for multiple videos to play at the same time when set to 0 or removed.